# Pandas apply function using another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use the apply function on my dataframe ('homes') that has multi index ('states' and 'RegionName'). The function i use tries to check if the combination of state and Region Name is matched by my other data frame ('UT').
when applying this function:

```
homes['UT']=homes.apply(lambda row: 1 if 
ut[(ut['State']==states[homes.iloc[row].name[0]]) &
         (ut['RegionName']==homes.iloc[row].name[1])] else 0, axis=1)
```

i get an error saying basicaly that my index is out of bounds.

I tried a few things like converting the other dataframe to two lists and check if the rows of my dataframe are in those lists but still getting the same error.

my ut dataframe head:

```
State   RegionName
1   Alabama Auburn
2   Alabama Florence
3   Alabama Jacksonville
4   Alabama Livingston
5   Alabama Montevallo
```

my home data frame head:

```
        2000q1  2000q2  2000q3  2000q4
State   RegionName              
New York    New York    NaN NaN NaN NaN
California  Los Angeles 207066.666667   214466.666667   220966.666667   226166.666667
Illinois    Chicago 138400.000000   143633.333333   147866.666667   152133.333333
Pennsylvania    Philadelphia    53000.000000    53633.333333    54133.333333    54700.000000
Arizona Phoenix 111833.333333   114366.666667   116000.000000   117400.000000
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you mind giving some useless parts of your dataframes ? Some code that we could reproduce end-to-end. :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks. i'm not sure how to add the data i have. i will try the links @Clijsters have provided and would edit the question

Comment: @LiorT, you can try `your_dataframe.head()` to give us a sample of your dataframe. Be sure to give us only the needed columns. you can also try `to_clipboard()` if the output doesn't look pretty

Comment: You might be looking for something like homes['UT'] = homes.apply(lambda row: 1 if (row.name[0] in list_state) & (row.name[1] in list_region) else 0, axis=1). list_state and list_region are two lists generated from your UT dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer thank to @user8505495.

the code should be like this:

```
homes['UT']=homes.apply(lambda row: 1 if (row.name[0]+', '+row.name[1] in ut['full'].values) else 0, axis=1)
```

i have no idea why it works but it does. thanks for all the help!